# Am I correctly adjusting image brightness?

Tags: java, image-processing, language-agnostic, processing

I'm trying to do something I hope is simple: change the overall brightness in a resulting image if the overall brightness of the source image is past a certain threshold value.

My logic so far is fairly simple:

1. get the difference between the target max. brightness and the source
   image overall brightness
2. normalize the difference
3. if the difference is greater than 0 then use the normalized brightness difference to
   'dimm'/subtract brightness on the resulting pixel

I've got a very simple 'runnable' prototype written in [Processing](http://processing.org)/(java) to illustrate the idea, but the programming language is less important

```
import java.util.Arrays;
PImage normal,dimmed;

int s  = 40;//preview scale factor
int w  = 8;//pixels width
int h  = 8;//pixels height
int np = w*h;//total number of pixels 
int b = 255;//current pixel brush brightness
float nb = 0;//normal image brightness
float mb = 64;//max brightness
float db = 0;//dimmed image brightness

void setup(){
  noSmooth();fill(127);
  size(w*s*2,h*s);
  normal = createImage(w,h,RGB);
  dimmed = createImage(w,h,RGB);
}
void draw(){
  image(normal,0,0,w*s,h*s);
  image(dimmed,w*s,0,w*s,h*s);
  text("original brightness: "+nb+" max: " + mb +"\ndimmed brightness: " + db,10,15);
}
void mouseDragged(){
  if(mouseX < w*s){
    normal.set(mouseX/s,mouseY/s,color(b));
    //average brightness
    nb = getBrightness(normal);
    //dimm if needed
    float bd   = (nb-mb)/255.0;//normalized brightness difference
    println(nb-mb+"/"+bd);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < np; i++)
      dimmed.pixels[i] = color(brightness(normal.pixels[i]) - (bd > 0 ? bd * 255.0 : 0));//copy brightness and subtract
    dimmed.updatePixels();
    //done dimming, compare
    db = getBrightness(dimmed);
  }
}
void keyPressed(){
  if(key == '-' && b > 0) b--;
  if(key == '=' && b < 255) b++; 
  if(key == ' ') {Arrays.fill(normal.pixels,0);normal.updatePixels();}
}
float getBrightness(PImage img){
  float ab = 0;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < np; i++) ab += brightness(img.pixels[i]);
  return (ab/np);
}
```

Does my logic make sense or should I take a different approach ? Also, am I correctly applying that logic in code. I'm in doubt because sometimes the overall brightness of the resulting image is higher than the target/maximum brightness and I'm not sure why.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem might be how colours in Processing are handled.
Here is a modifier version that simply uses a 2d array of ints(brightness values):

```
int s  = 40;//preview scale factor
int w  = 8;//pixels width
int h  = 8;//pixels height
int np = w*h;//total number of pixels 
int b = 255;//current pixel brush brightness
float nb = 0;//normal image brightness
float mb = 64;//max brightness
float db = 0;//dimmed image brightness

int[][] normal,dimmed;

void setup(){
  noSmooth();fill(127);
  size(w*s*2,h*s);
  normal = new int[w][h];
  dimmed = new int[w][h];
}
void draw(){
  background(0);//clear
  for(int y = 0; y  < h ; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < w ; x++){
      fill(normal[x][y]);
      rect(x*s,y*s,s,s);//draw a scaled pixel representation
      fill(dimmed[x][y]);
      rect((x*s)+(w*s),y*s,s,s);
    }
  }
  fill(127);text("original brightness: "+nb+" max: " + mb +"\ndimmed brightness: " + db,10,15);
}
void mouseDragged(){
  if((mouseX > 0 && mouseX < w*s)&&(mouseY > 0 && mouseY < h*s)){
    normal[mouseX/s][mouseY/s] = b;
    //average brightness
    nb = getBrightness(normal);
    //dimm if needed
    float bd   = (nb-mb)/255.0;//normalized brightness difference
    println(nb-mb+"/"+bd);

    for(int y = 0; y  < h ; y++)
      for(int x = 0; x < w ; x++)
        dimmed[x][y] = normal[x][y] - (int)(bd > 0 ? bd * 255.0 : 0);
    //done dimming, compare
    db = getBrightness(dimmed);
  }
}
void keyPressed(){
  if(key == '-' && b > 0) b--;
  if(key == '=' && b < 255) b++; 
  if(key == ' ') {
    for(int y = 0; y  < h ; y++)
      for(int x = 0; x < w ; x++)
        normal[x][y] = 0;
  }
}
float getBrightness(int[][] img){
  float ab = 0;
  for(int y = 0; y  < h ; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < w ; x++)
      ab += img[x][y];
  return (ab/np);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want change just brightness you could use [tint(b)](http://processing.org/tutorials/pixels/) with one argument where:

- `b = 255` (original image)
- `b = 0` (dark image)

In code you just change `draw()`

```
void draw(){
  image(normal,0,0,w*s,h*s);
  tint(b);
  image(dimmed,w*s,0,w*s,h*s);     
}
```